# java swing how to fixed problem with print value

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

I am programming java swing, knapsack algorithm
I have four arguments, I want take value by textFiled

n --> elements

wt --> weight

val --> value

W --> capacity

should print `val` in label java
My code doesn't print anything in label
I don't why that
There is no error

In this my code:
Algorithm inside action button 'run'

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Knapsack_frame extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JLabel lebel_out;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Knapsack_frame frame = new Knapsack_frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Knapsack_frame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 871, 531);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    
    

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.setBounds(408, 121, 213, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    
    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(408, 149, 213, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    
    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    textField_2.setBounds(408, 189, 213, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    
    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBounds(408, 228, 213, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    lebel_out = new JLabel("");
    lebel_out.setBounds(192, 289, 499, 52);
    contentPane.add(lebel_out);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter number of elements :");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(211, 124, 166, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    // here button run 
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Knapsack Run");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // here my algorithm Knapsack
             //four argement, input by text Filed 
            class Zero_One_Knapsack
            {
                public void solve(int[] wt, int[] val, int W, int N)
                {
                    int NEGATIVE_INFINITY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    int[][] m = new int[N + 1][W + 1];
                    int[][] sol = new int[N + 1][W + 1];
                    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= W; j++)
                        {
                            int m1 = m[i - 1][j];
                            int m2 = NEGATIVE_INFINITY; 
                            if (j >= wt[i])
                                m2 = m[i - 1][j - wt[i]] + val[i];
                            m[i][j] = Math.max(m1, m2);
                            sol[i][j] = m2 > m1 ? 1 : 0;
                        }
                    }        
                    int[] selected = new int[N + 1];
                    for (int n = N, w = W; n > 0; n--)
                    {
                        if (sol[n][w] != 0)
                        {
                            selected[n] = 1;
                            w = w - wt[n];
                        }
                        else
                            selected[n] = 0;
                    }
                    
                    for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++)
                        if (selected[i] == 1)
                   
                lebel_out.setText("\nItems with weight "+ val[i] + "  " + "are selected by knapsack 
                 algorithm."  );
                }
                public void main (String[] args) 
                {
                   
                    Zero_One_Knapsack ks = new Zero_One_Knapsack();
             
                  int n = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    int[] wt = new int[n + 1];
                    int[] val = new int[n + 1];
             //----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    int valueWt =Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                        wt[i] = valueWt;
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    int valueV =Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());
                    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                        val[i] =  valueV;
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 
                    int W = Integer.parseInt(textField_4.getText());
                    ks.solve(wt, val, W, n);
                 
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(355, 41, 192, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    
    JLabel lblEnterWeightFor = new JLabel("Enter weight for 4 elements :");
    lblEnterWeightFor.setBounds(211, 152, 166, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterWeightFor);
    
    JLabel lblEnterValueFor = new JLabel("Enter value for 4 elements :");
    lblEnterValueFor.setBounds(211, 189, 166, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterValueFor);
    
    JLabel lblEnterCapacity = new JLabel("Enter capacity :");
    lblEnterCapacity.setBounds(211, 231, 166, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnterCapacity);
    
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: The action listener never constructs a `Zero_One_Knapsack` instance and calls its `solve` method.  The entirety of the `actionPerformed` method is just the _declaration_ of that class; it doesn't actually **do** anything.

Comment: yes, this correct, Now, i have another problem, in need enter multiple int from textFiled

Comment: for example number element 2 , then need entry  two number in textFiled and split between them by comma

Comment: Accepting multiple values in a single text field is not the best GUI design practice;  why not just use two text fields?  That said, it's not hard to do.  Just use `split("\\s*,\\s*")` on the field text to separate the two numbers. You could also use a regular expression to parse the field contents, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't extend `JFrame` unnecessarily
2. Don't use `null`/`AbsoluteLayout` have a look here for some [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow) choices
3. Don't manually call `setBounds` on components, use a `LayoutManager` and let the components size themselves and simply call `pack()` on the `JFrame`
4. Don't call `setContentPane` of the `JFrame` to simply add a `JPanel`, either call `JFrame#getContentPane()` or simple just call `JFrame#add(...)`, maybe thats my preference
5. Your class names are not something you usually see in Java (underscores lower cased letters), they should be Pascal Cased i.e. `KnapsackApp`, `ZeroOneKnapsack` no underscores etc. although its valid its not the normal convention.
6. Same applies to your variable names (textField_1) usually this would be Camel Cased i.e. `textField1` also probably would be better to give them better names i.e. `elementsLabel`.
7. Separate your concerns, you have a class nested in a `JButton`s `actionPerformed` (I assume to access `JTextField`s etc, but that's not necessary), create it in a separate file, pass in arguments to the `solve` method  and return the result which you then  use to set the *results* `JLabel` value.
8. You don't even create a instance of the `Zero_One_Knapsack` class to call `solve` in the buttons `actionPerformed`.
9. Perhaps use a `SwingWorker` to do the work in the background and publish the results to the UI after (so the UI doesn't freeze) if its even possible for the Knapsack to take that long.
10. To accept comma separted integers and convert them into an array of integers you could siply use Java 8 Streams:

```
String line = "1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,3,"; // example from textFeild.getText()
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Here is the code refactored to give you some idea of what you should be aiming for, I'm no saying it works as you want, but hopefully with some things cleaned up you will be given a good foundation and understanding to finish it up:

[image]

**KnapsackApp.java:**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class KnapsackApp {

    public KnapsackApp() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(KnapsackApp::new);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // setup JPanel and LayoutManager
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel elementsLabel = new JLabel("Enter number of elements :");
        panel.add(elementsLabel);
        JTextField elementsTextField = new JTextField();
        elementsTextField.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(elementsTextField);

        JLabel lblEnterWeightFor = new JLabel("Enter weight for 4 elements :");
        panel.add(lblEnterWeightFor);
        JTextField weightTextField = new JTextField();
        weightTextField.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(weightTextField);

        JLabel lblEnterValueFor = new JLabel("Enter value for 4 elements :");
        panel.add(lblEnterValueFor);
        JTextField valueTextFields = new JTextField();
        valueTextFields.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(valueTextFields);

        JLabel lblEnterCapacity = new JLabel("Enter capacity :");
        panel.add(lblEnterCapacity);
        JTextField capacityTextField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(capacityTextField);
        capacityTextField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result: ");
        panel.add(resultLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Knapsack Run");
        panel.add(btnNewButton);

        btnNewButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(elementsTextField.getText());
            int[] wt = new int[n + 1];
            int[] val = new int[n + 1];

            int valueWt = Integer.parseInt(weightTextField.getText());
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                wt[i] = valueWt;
            }
            int valueV = Integer.parseInt(valueTextFields.getText());
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                val[i] = valueV;
            }

            int W = Integer.parseInt(capacityTextField.getText());

            SwingWorker backgroundWorker = new SwingWorker<Integer, Void>() {
                @Override
                public Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    // do the work
                    return new ZeroOneKnapsack().solve(wt, val, W, n);
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    int result;
                    try {
                        // get and display the result from solve
                        result = get();
                        resultLabel.setText("Result: " + result);
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(KnapsackApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            backgroundWorker.execute();
        });

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**ZeroOneKnapsack.java:**

```
public class ZeroOneKnapsack {

    public int solve(int[] wt, int[] val, int W, int N) {
        int NEGATIVE_INFINITY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int[][] m = new int[N + 1][W + 1];
        int[][] sol = new int[N + 1][W + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= W; j++) {
                int m1 = m[i - 1][j];
                int m2 = NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                if (j >= wt[i]) {
                    m2 = m[i - 1][j - wt[i]] + val[i];
                }
                m[i][j] = Math.max(m1, m2);
                sol[i][j] = m2 > m1 ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }
        int[] selected = new int[N + 1];
        for (int n = N, w = W; n > 0; n--) {
            if (sol[n][w] != 0) {
                selected[n] = 1;
                w = w - wt[n];
            } else {
                selected[n] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++) {
            if (selected[i] == 1) {
                return val[i];
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```